# how to update mongo document without knowing what has been modified

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, server

I need a more or less very general advice how to update my DB.

I have a huge JSON (ugly doubly nested) data coming from the client and what's worse is that I do not know which particular one has been modified, which means I can't use `{ $set: something ..`

I desinged referenced documents in order to avoid doubly nested array.

Therefore I have 5 collections.

locations
  floors
    stores
    restrooms
    benches

e.g. 
location has floors
floor has stores, restrooms, and benches and so on.

here is my simplified schema

```
const Location = new Schema({
  floors: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'FloorSchema',
  }],
});

const FloorSchema = new Schema({
  stores: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'StoreSchema',
  }],
  restrooms: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'RestroomSchema',
  }],
  benches: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'BenchSchema',
  }],
});
```

From the client side, there is no api request until the changes are done.
So the first request I get from the client is huge map data with no history recorded.

Do you think it is a reasonable idea to drop the entire collections (except the location collection) and save a whole new map data instead of investigating what has been modified?

Thank you,

======
I found one [question&answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652525/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-the-whole-document-all-fields-in-mongodb/43662135#43662135) which seems to be very relevant. 
I will try the first solution

Comment: There is nothing "doubly nested" about this. This is "referenced" which means all the actual data resides in separate collections. Not "nested" within arrays.

Comment: Thank you Neil, yes you are correct. My question was wrong. My intention was that the referenced schemas have bunch of other meta data that I have no clue whether they are modified or not. 

Do you think there is no problem using 'update' method of mongoDB or mongoose here? This question was my intended general question.. so. Thanks for your comment always. To me, removing the whole data sounds very stupid..but I'm not sure if there is a use case that sometimes it is better to do so.

Comment: If your question is wrong then correct your question and write your clear explanation of what you really need to do in there instead. This is not a chat room and nobody has time for back and forth discussion. Your explanation belongs in your question and not in conversation. Fix your question. Right now I have no clue what you really need to do and neither does anybody else looking at it. The title is wrong. The content is wrong and shows nothing, Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and all it's related links

Comment: Thanks Neil, a lesson learned. I read the 'how-to-ask' link.  Apologies if my edited question is still not clear.